# Selecting the second td selector of the 3 tr selector C# PlayWright

Tags: c#, css, web-applications, playwright

Im trying the get the text from an element from a web-app using the Playwright-tool
The text is located in the 2nd td of the 3rd tr of the list.

```
<table _ngcontent-oyw-c36>
  <tbody _ngcontent-oyw-c36>
   <tr _ngcontent-oyw-c36>...</tr>
   <tr _ngcontent-oyw-c36>...</tr>
   <tr _ngcontent-oyw-c36>...</tr>
     <td _ngcontent-oyw-c36>...</td>
     <td _ngcontent-oyw-c36>"The text I need"</td>
```

So the issue is that all the tr's and td's dont have a name or id or anything.

I tried

```
var rowWithStartDateTime = page1.Locator("app-production-order-info div table tbody tr:last-child");

var productieorderStartTime = rowWithStartDateTime.Locator("td:nth-child(2)").InnerTextAsync();
```

`
I tried the upper code with more and less steps in the path.
While debugging when hovering over the var productieorderStartTime it gives the following:

Id = 265, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet comupeted}"

I also tried doing it directly with the following paths

("tbody tr:first-child td:nth-hild(2)")
and
("div table tbdoy tr:last-child td:last-child")

While hovering over I get the same message as the first example
Id = ***, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet comupeted}"

Comment: The HTML doesn't look valid. What are these attributes? Shouldn't `tbdoy` be `tbody`? I don't see much clarity here.

Comment: I dont know what atributes these are. This is the HTML it shows. 
And you were right. It is tbody instead of tdboy. I hoped it fixed the issue but sadly enough it did not.

Comment: Are you sure the html you pasted in your post is correct?

Comment: @JakyRuby yes . Why?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a simple error.

I had to `await` the `.InnerTextAsync();`

This code worked resulted in the desired string:

```
var rowWithStartDateTime = await page1.Locator("table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)").InnerTextAsync();
```